# How Can I Run a Process to a specific physical core using OpenMPI?

Tags: openmpi

How Can I Run a Process to a specific physical core without using processor affinity or other virtual techniques only using OpenMPI in my intel core i5 processor?

Comment: I suggest you read the manpage of Open MPI's `mpirun`.

Comment: I am not understanding the manual. can you help me give an example? I want to run the process on specific core like core 0 or core 1. these cores need to be physical, not virtual.